# Passing insulated duct through floor

Tags: ducts, hole

A bathroom exhaust fan's instructions call for 4 inch *insulated* flexible duct to minimize noise and to prevent condensation in the attic space.

The duct has to pass through the attic's floor boards at one point.   Do I need to cut a hole in the attic floor big enough for the insulated duct, which would be about a 9 inch hole?   Or can I cut the duct and use a 4 inch splice to go through the attic floor, so the insulation does not pass through?

If it was A/C air I'd expect condensation on the floor boards around the splice if I did this, but with a bathroom exhaust I wonder if it's ok?

For clarity, the hole is in floor board not joists and it enters unfinished crawl space in the attic.

Comment: Imagine adding some insulation around the splice hole would good enough.  Will save cold air from the attic from coming in where it is not wanted at least.

Answer (score 0):

Since it is an unoccupied area I think the best and in the long term the least problematic is to not splice the duct. I have no idea where you are but in the northern area where I live that would cause an ice dam
and or ice blockage to form during freezing weather. This ice like all others will melt when it gets warm. The water from this melting ice will flow down hill back into the fan.

Comment: I don't understand why splicing the duct where it passes through the attic *floorboard* would affect ice damming on the roof, which is several feet higher.  But you've raised a good point that I didn't consider.  I should either get a roof vent with a tall enough flange to rise above any potential ice damming, or perhaps vent through the soffit, which is an option.   Maybe that should be a new question.

Comment: Once again, on this site in particular, as you point out, location is a really significant factor to consider when producing answers.

Answer (score 0):

If you can find some plastic tubing the right o.d. to fit snugly inside the insulated pipe, that would make the job easier, and alleviate condensation at times when the loft is very cold. Obviously putting some lagging around that tubing where it's exposed in the loft. Duct tape to seal the joints will go down well too. Plastic rather than any metal tubing is preferrable. Maybe sewer pipe or suchlike if you can't find an actual pipe designed just for that purpose.